# Filter a list of lists to remove common list elements by name

Tags: r, list, filter

Say we had a list of lists of the form

```
X = list(list("a" = list(1, 2, 3), "a" = list(1, 2, 3), "c" = list(3, 4, 5), "d" = list(4, 5, 6)), 
         list("a" = list(1, 2, 3), "b" = list(2, 3, 4), "e" = list(5, 6, 7), "d" = list(4, 5, 6)),
         list("d" = list(4, 5, 6), "c" = list(3, 4, 5), "c" = list(3, 4, 5), "d" = list(4, 5, 6)),
         list("c" = list(3, 4, 5), "d" = list(4, 5, 6), "d" = list(4, 5, 6), "e" = list(5, 6, 7)),
         list("b" = list(2, 3, 4), "a" = list(1, 2, 3), "f" = list(6, 7, 8), "c" = list(3, 4, 5)))
```

What I would like to do is to remove elements, by name, from list j if the element appears in list i (with i < j). The simplest way I came up with was to iterate from the last list to the first (not inclusive) and

1. unlist all the lists up to list j
2. take the set difference of list j with the unlisted elements
3. select those elements in the set difference from list j

In code

```
Y = rev(lapply(length(X):2, function(j) {sel = setdiff(names(X[[j]]), names(unlist(X[1:(j-1)], recursive = FALSE)))
                                         X[[j]][sel]}))
```

which yields

```
Y = list(list("b" = list(2, 3, 4), "e" = list(5, 6, 7)), # removed "a", "d" as they appeared in the first list
         list(),                                         # removed all elements as they appeared in the first and second lists
         list(),                                         # removed all elements as they appeared in the first, second and third lists
         list("f" = list(6, 7, 8)))                      # removed "b", "a", "c" as they appeared in the first, second, third and fourth lists
```

This gives almost the correct result, though the problem is that the new list Y does not contain the first list X[[1]]. While I could simply append X[[1]] to the front of the list, due to the size of the lists it would be preferable to simply overwrite X on the fly rather than constructing an entirely new list, as the code above does, and setting it equal to X.

Therefore, what I would like to do is to filter X **using the base R Filter only** (I don't have access to a lot of different packages and so would also prefer to use base objects such as Map, Reduce etc. in conjunction if possible) to obtain the list of lists as prescribed above. However I was unable to get the filtering to work, even when using a rolling window. Could someone please show me how to do this?

Comment: I have a working version using for loops, if you'd be okay with that?

Comment: @Mark I believe for loops may be too slow due to the size of the sublists (~1e5 - 1e6) and how many sublists there are (~10 - 100).

Comment: I don't know if *just* using Filter would work in this case, as you're not really filtering the top level, you're filtering the elements of each sublist

Comment: I could see something working with lapply applying Filter to each sublist, but I'd be surprised if nothing but Filter can be used to solve this

Comment: `Reduce` is just a `for` loop hidden by some niceties, so I'd at least consider the loop code. There's no reason it would have to be painfully slow.

Comment: if you can give me a rough pseudocode idea of how a filter would work, then I'm happy to implement it. The issue is going from looping through the unlisted list to then working on the nested one. There needs to be some kind of loop to retain the nested structure

Comment: @Mark I'm happy with whatever is fastest and does not take up too much memory, even for very short periods. The code I have above is quite fast but suffers from memory issues when constructing the list Y (I essentially have two lists X, Y that are very similar in size). For this reason I thought Filtering would be the best option, though I could not get it to work myself. If not, I'm open to other suggestions.

Comment: @thelatemail I suggested Reduce only because I was looking to use base functions. If there are faster or less memory intensive methods, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Map`/`Reduce` attempt:

```
out <- Map(
    \(l,n) l[names(l) %in% setdiff(names(l), n)],
    X,
    c(list(NA), head(Reduce(union, lapply(X, names), accumulate=TRUE), -1))
)
```

Annotated code:

```
lapply(X, names)
```

gets the names for each list,

```
Reduce(union, lapply(X, names), accumulate=TRUE)
```

which are then added up (ac)cumulatively at each step so all names represented up to this point are returned, and then this

```
c(list(NA), head(Reduce(union, lapply(X, names), accumulate=TRUE), -1))
```

removes the last result of the accumulation and binds a `list(NA)` to the start so that this set of accumulation is always compared to the previous set in the original `X` list.

Result seems to match as expected:

```
dput(out)
##list(
##    list(a = list(1, 2, 3), a = list(1, 2, 3), c = list(3, 4, 5), d = list(4, 5, 6)),
##    list(b = list(2, 3, 4), e = list(5, 6, 7)),
##    structure(list(), names = character(0)),
##    structure(list(), names = character(0)), 
##    list(f = list(6, 7, 8))
##)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that looks great. Just a few questions; 1. What is the 'structure' object in the output? Is this something unique to 'dput'? 2. Could you comment the code to outline specifically what is happening? I'm mainly after the third line where you bind the head of some object to an empty list, I'm not quite following what is happening.

Comment: Actually I think I understand it now. I will compare it against my code and see how this compares with speed and memory (I think it will perform better). Thanks again.

Comment: @MatthewCassell - added some annotations.